# Not Harry Potter: Book about a boy with a golden egg who has to go underwater

Tags: story-identification

In like 2004 I read this book about a boy who had to go on some magical journey and there was something to do with a golden egg and I know at one point he had to go underwater. No, it was not Harry Potter. I remember the cover of the book most. There was like an oval shape in the middle and the boy was drawn in there and he was holding the golden egg I think. And I believe there was a tree as well.

Comment: I was going to say Harry Potter from the title... :-p

Comment: Yeah it's not that :/